# Pulling the firebase documents those that comes before/above the specified document

Tags: angular, database, firebase, loaddata, ngx-pagination

Is there a way we can pull the Firebase documents that comes before/above the specified document Id.?? If so can someone please suggest to me how I can achieve that?
I'm using the ngx-pagination and I'm not pulling all the documents at once. Im pulling the data only when the next page has been hit and it's working fine by using the startAfter() method. I want to know if there are any predefined methods like startAfter() for pulling the documents that comes before the mentioned documentId.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `startAfter` is a method called `endBefore`. You can pass in the same information as you'd pass to `startAfter`, but get the documents *before* the so-called cursor document.

For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [paginating with cursors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and the [reference documentation for `endBefore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#endbefore).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply... I would try this and come back soon ... :)